# Redirect all traffic on my hotspot to a local web server

Tags: webserver, hotspot, local

I am trying to set up a Linksys WTR160NL router with DD-WRT firmware (version: DD-WRT v24-sp2  std) to redirect all internet traffic to the single IP address 192.168.xxx.xxx (a small local web server where my website is hosted). This is for the wifi in my small café.

No internet connection is needed.

I do not want to set up a splash/accept page.

Comment: I try to be more clear as possible:
Material used:
  a pc with ubuntu installed that hosts my website web in HTML
  a linksys router WRT160NL WIFI open, with dd WRT LAN connected to pc
  no internet connection
,when  the customer connected to my  wifi network and the opening traffic,  the browser must   appear the index / page of the site (192.168.xx.xx: 80)  all the system work,
  the customer need digit the address in the browser for see my web site…
I try make this automatic….suggestions?

Comment: So actually you *do* want a splash page (AKA captive portal).

Comment: NoCatsplash requires you to have -An active internet connection -

Comment: And all the sistem work without internet...

Comment: It doesn’t matter what some software requires. It’s just a fact: You want users to be directed to a specific page. This is *the very definition* of a captive portal.

Comment: It is right !    I want users to be directed to a specific page.

Comment: Just last question, actually you provide a wifi without internet? to order things or something? or you want to access your website from local network if someone connect from your network? and in the same time they can use internet ?

Comment: Just last question, actually you provide a wifi without internet?

The customer are invited to connect to my local free wifi for consult my website where is listed  my product.

 to order things or something?
 No to order. only consulting

 or you want to access your website from local network if someone connect from your network?
My website it is hosted in my small pc (lan connect to the router)
 
and in the same time they can use internet ?
for internet will be need try other or personal connection